# Best practice: React useEffect hook dependencies when setting loading state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dependencies, fetch-api

I'm learning React hooks and am struggling with linting rules around exhaustive deps. In particular, I want to set a status of "loading" when an API call is being made (showing a loading message to the user, for example), then set it to "idle" when the call is returned, but the linter says there are missing dependencies. Here's the hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setStatus(STATUSES.LOADING);
    getData()
      .then(result => {
        setStatus(STATUSES.IDLE);
        setData(result);
      });
  }, []);
```

According to the linter, I should be adding dependencies for STATUSES.LOADING and STATUSES.IDLE - this seems counterintuitive though, as I don't want to arbitrarily re-run the API call whenever the status is changed.

I don't want to just ignore the warning, so is there a better pattern here to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: what is STATUSES?

Comment: @Samira it's just an enum containing the two loading states - for the purposes of this example we could just as easily replace them with "loading" and "idle" strings.

Comment: @Samira interestingly, I just tried doing exactly that (i.e. replacing the enum with simple strings) and the linting error vanished... I don't understand the distinction though! It's just a constant.

Comment: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/stop-using-isloading-booleans

Comment: @Vikas thank you - have been meaning to read up on state machines a bit more

Answer (score 0):

The linting rule does not know whether the dependencies are going to change or not. It is there to avoid unexpected bugs in future like if the value is being provided from parent component and can change there.